# ImportError: tlz.curry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import, dask

I installed Dask using this command on jupyter notebook from Anaconda navigator(local)

```
 !pip install "dask[complete]"  --quiet
```

And, I imported the dataframe using this command.

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
```

And,  I got this error.

Additional note: It was fine importing on online notebook, but when I import on local workspace it gives me this error.

---

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-13-abfee5ccc14e> in <module>
          1 import os
          2 import pandas as pd
    ----> 3 import dask
          4 import dask.dataframe as dd
          5 import opendatasets as od
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\__init__.py in <module>
          1 from dask import config, datasets
          2 from dask._version import get_versions
    ----> 3 from dask.base import (
          4     annotate,
          5     compute,
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in <module>
         20 
         21 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
    ---> 22 from tlz import curry, groupby, identity, merge
         23 from tlz.functoolz import Compose
         24 
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tlz\_build_tlz.py in exec_module(self, module)
         52 
         53     def exec_module(self, module):
    ---> 54         toolz_mods = self._load_toolz(module.__name__)
         55         fast_mod = toolz_mods.get('cytoolz') or toolz_mods['toolz']
         56         slow_mod = toolz_mods.get('toolz') or toolz_mods['cytoolz']
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tlz\_build_tlz.py in _load_toolz(self, fullname)
         26             pass
         27         if not rv:
    ---> 28             raise ImportError(fullname)
         29         return rv
         30 
    
    ImportError: tlz.curry
```

How can I fix this. Thank you in advance! :).

Comment: if you install without `--quiet`, are there any error messages?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado yes, there is still an error message.

Comment: sorry - I mean is there an error that occurs when installing dask?

Comment: There isn't any error when installing Dask. The error only occurs when I am importing the library.

Comment: Please give details of your OS, how python was originally installed, and the output of `pip list` after attempted installation.

Comment: @mdurant The importing issues disappeared after I reinstalled anaconda navigator. However, another libraries issues seem to emerge. The problem is due to "PATH" of installed libraries. I am still finding a way to fix path issue though.

Comment: You should typically have conda and navigator in their own environment, and the analysis stuff like dask in another. And use conda (mamba) not pip to install them!

Comment: @mdurant Would you mind to explain when should I use pip and conda? Should I use both to play safe?

Comment: No, don't do that! Use conda for everything you can, and use it first. Use pip only when you must, after all conda deps are in, as it can mess up subsequent installations.